# Changes to a Merged CSV file not saving

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, editing

I am merging two csv files that relate to a system process. However I want to make a like change to the Header.
Examples of csv file I'm using (example process: 'python'):

```
Date,      Process(python)\% Processor Time, Process(python)\Thread Count, Process(python)\Working Set
xx/xx/xx    xxxx                                    xxxx                            xxxx
xx/xx/xx    xxxx                                    xxxx                            xxxx
xx/xx/xx    xxxx                                    xxxx                            xxxx
xx/xx/xx    xxxx                                    xxxx                            xxxx
xx/xx/xx    xxxx                                    xxxx                            xxxx
```

I have a script which will truncate the string removing the unwanted `'Process(python)\'` part of the string.
Using a print statement I can verify that the desired string is being printed to the screen.

```
% Processor Time
Thread Count
Working Set
```

However when I save this new merged file these changes aren't being saved. How do I ensure the changes I make to remove the unwanted `'Process(python)\'` is being saved to the output file?

My code:

```
def merge_process_csv(path,processes):
    for process_name in processes:
        a = pd.read_csv(path+process_name+"_data_1.csv")
        b = pd.read_csv(path+process_name+"_data_2.csv")
        b = b.dropna(axis=1)
        merged = a.merge(b, on='Date')

        csvReader = csv.reader(merged)
        for row in csvReader:
            #Changes 'Process(python)\% Processor Time' into '% Processor Time'
            row = truncate_string(row[0],"\\",1)
            print row

        merged.to_csv(path+process_name+".csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making changes to csvReader but not to `merged`. If all you want to do adjust the header row, you can replace:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(merged)
for row in csvReader:
    #Changes 'Process(python)\% Processor Time' into '% Processor Time'
    row = truncate_string(row[0],"\\",1)
    print row
```

with

```
merged.columns = [col[-1] for col in merged.columns.str.split('\\')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what do I define `df` as?

Comment: My bad. That should be ``merged``. I've edited my answer.